# Beamer note alert

Tags: beamer, overlays

Apparently, the following does not achieve what I want, namely highlighting the note when it's uncovered:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{pgfpages}
\AtBeginNote{\beamerdefaultoverlayspecification{<*>}}
\begin{document}
    \setbeameroption{show notes on second screen=right} % Both
    \begin{frame}
        \begin{itemize}[<+->]
            \item Something \note<.->[item]{\alert<.>{Hallo!}}
            \item Something \note<.->[item]{\alert<.>{Hallo!}}
            \item Something \note<.->[item]{\alert<.>{Hallo!}}
        \end{itemize}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

When inspecting the `beamerpauses` counter, there seems to be something off; it jumps right from 1 to 4, probably because the notes-page is processed later. But also the following does not work:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeameroption{show notes on second screen=right}
\AtBeginNote{\beamerdefaultoverlayspecification{<*>}}
\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        \begin{itemize}
            \item<1-> Something \note<1->[item]{\alert<1>{Hallo!}}
            \item<2-> Something \note<2->[item]{\alert<2>{Hallo!}}
            \item<3-> Something \note<3->[item]{\alert<3>{Hallo!}}
        \end{itemize}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Is there a smarter way to achieve what I want?

Comment: With `\alert<.>{...}` you don't increase the pause counter of the note page and thus they will all be alerted on the first note slide

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz That means that the counters on the slides and its notes don't have anything to do with each other?

Answer (score 0):

If your itemize isn't the last slide in the frame, you could do something like this:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeameroption{show notes on second screen=right} % Both
\AtBeginNote{\beamerdefaultoverlayspecification{<*>}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        \begin{itemize}[<+->]
            \item Something \note<.->[item]{\alert<+>{Hallo!}}
            \item Something \note<.->[item]{\alert<+>{Hallo!}}
            \item Something \note<.->[item]{\alert<+>{Hallo!}}
        \end{itemize}
        \uncover<+>{one more overlay}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: If you remove `\uncover<+>{one more overlay}`, you see that the `alert` for the last bullet point stops working.

Comment: @Bubaya That's why I said `If your itemize isn't the last slide in the frame`

Comment: Ah, sorry. Didn't read that. In any case, that does not explain what goes wrong, see my second example that I added.

Comment: @Bubaya `\alert<3>{Hallo!}` will work if it is not the last slide in the frame

Comment: Yes, but what if I want to highlight the note going with the last slide of the frame?

Comment: make one more slide and delete the page in the final version